# Make Gist embed scrollable

Tags: wordpress, git, embed, gist

is it possible to make gist embed script have vertical scroll bar? I want to embed my gist to my blog post, but it's a long code. I want my gist look like this in my blog post :

[image: Scrollable code container]

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution is to add the following code to your CSS:

```
.gist-data{
    height:250px; // Any height
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

This will limit the height of the gist's container, I tried other wrappers around it and this was the first one to limit the height.

Depending on specificity, you may need to add `!important` in your styles.

Comment: I prefer to use `max-height: 250px;` to avoid short gists to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

One WordPress project which provides that kind of feature would be "[Embed GitHub Gist / Gist height (7 posts)](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-embed-github-gist-gist-height)".

> I wanted to add a gist height for really long gists that would result in a scrollbar for the embed.
>   Here's the patch to achieve this for the current trunk using a height parameter to the shortcode.

The most recent version is at [this project](https://gist.github.com/archon810/3200265/revisions).

Some of that work might have been included in "[dflydev/embed-github-gist](https://github.com/dflydev/embed-github-gist)".