# Embed Gist without vertical scrolling

Tags: css, gist

When I embed a long gist (in this case of a [Jupyter Notebook](https://gist.github.com/goerz/865eb143cc615676ee76f257ae7459ee#file-tls_dissipator_superop-ipynb)), the resulting box on my website has vertical scrollbars. I'd like to avoid these scrollbars and just have a longer page (in the same way it's on the actual gist website). Is there any way to do this, with CSS or otherwise?

I'm basically looking for the exact opposite to
[Make Gist embed scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323057/make-gist-embed-scrollable)

Note that specifying a minimum height in CSS does not work: It produces a white box of the correct size, but the content is still scrolling in the top part of that box only

Answer (score 1):

As I can check, the embed code inserts an `iframe` and there is no simply way to detect the height of that document (cross-domain).

This might help: [Resize Cross Domain Iframe Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086722/resize-cross-domain-iframe-height)

But keep in mind that the workarounds are overkill, I think.

Comment: That looks like overkill, indeed. I wish github would support passing some options to their embed script (like `scrolling="no"`)